# How to check the type of multiple variables in SASS

Tags: sass

I have created a large number of SASS variables which I need to check that they are in the correct format after a user has changed them.

For example, I have the following variables:

```
$varible1: true;
$variable2: false;
$variable3: true;
$variable4: "400, 500, 600";
$variable5: true;
$variable6: "foo bar buzz";
$variable7: 4;
$variable8: 9;
etc...
```

As you can see, not all my variables are booleans, some are numbers or strings too. However, each variable will always be expected to be a certain type (`$variable5` should always be a boolean etc). What I want to do is check each variables type and give out an error message if it is incorrect. I have written the following `@if` statement to check the first variable:

```
@if type-of($variable1) != bool {
    @error "'#{$variable1}' is not a valid value for $variable1, you must use a boolean.";
}
```

The problem is, I'm going to end up with a list of 30+ `@if` statements to check each variable. Is there a way that I can check `$variable1`, `$variable2`, `$variable3` and `$variable5` in one `@if` statement, and pass the variable name and value into the error message?

My only idea so far has to create another variable that is a list of all the variables I expect to be a boolean and then do an `@each` loop over it, something like:

```
$boolean-variables: $variable1, $variable2, $variable3...
@each $var in $boolean-variables {
    @if type-of($var) != bool {
        @error "'#{$var}' is not a valid value for $var, you must use a boolean.";
    }
}
```

Is this a good way of doing it, or are there other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I ended up using a map of the variable names and types and then looped over then, injecting the name and type into an error message.

I did however run into a couple of issues setting up the map. Firstly, the `key` cannot be a variable, as this returns the variable value rather than the name. I got round this by using the name of the variable, minus the `$`. This allowed me to see which variable I was looking at whilst still working as a `key`. Secondly, I needed to have the value of the variables, as well as the type. I set up the `value` for each pair to be another map, with the variable as the `key` and the type as the `value`. This meant I could then run another loop over this data to check these values. Below is an example of how my map was structured:

```
$setting-types: (
    variable-name1: ($variable-name1: bool),
    variable-name2: ($variable-name2: bool),
    variable-name3: ($variable-name3: list)
}
```

This effectively returns:

```
$setting-types: (
    variable-name1: (true: bool),
    variable-name2: (false: bool),
    variable-name3: (foo, bar, buzz: list)
}
```

I was then able to run an `@each` function over the map like so:

```
@each $setting, $data in $setting-types {
    $setting-name: $setting;
    @each $variable, $type in $data {
        @if type-of($variable) != $type {
            @error "'#{$variable}' is not a valid value for $#{$setting-name}, you must use a #{$type}.";
        }
    }
}
```

The first loop splits each variable in the map, and then the second loop goes over the variable value and expected data type. I then use `type-of()` to check what the data type for the variable is and if does not match what is written in the map, then the error is shown. I also set another variable after the first loop, which is just the `key` from the first loop, but can then be accessed in the second loop to help provide some clarity in the error message.

I hope this is clear enough for others to understand, should they need to do something similar.